# Error: undefined reference to '...' after trying to build app in fresh system installation

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, codeblocks

I am developing c++ application in Win7 OS using GCC compiler and Code::Blocks as IDE. I have everything set up and everything works. Now i need to move whole development environment to virtual machine so i have installed system, IDE compiler, copied whole project. I double checked all libraries and options and they are same. When i try to build application i get this errors (50) from build log(relevant parts):

```
-------------- Build: Debug in MagicReportsFull (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -std=c++11 -fexceptions -std=c++11 -g -IC:\Projects\MagicReportsFull\include -IC:\Projects\MagicReportsFull\ -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW" -IC:\Projects\MagicReportsFull -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW" -IC:\Projects\MagicReportsFull\include -c C:\Projects\MagicReportsFull\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
windres.exe   -J rc -O coff -i C:\Projects\MAGICR~1\resource.rc -o obj\Debug\resource.res
windres.exe   -J rc -O coff -i C:\Projects\MAGICR~1\version.rc -o obj\Debug\version.res
mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\Projects\MagicReportsFull\ -o bin\Debug\MagicReportsFull.exe obj\Debug\main.o  obj\Debug\resource.res obj\Debug\version.res  -lcomdlg32 -lgdi32 -luser32 -lshlwapi ..\..\CustomLibraries\lpng1636-build\libpng16.a ..\..\CustomLibraries\zlib-1.2.11-build\libzlibstatic.a ..\..\CustomLibraries\libharu-RELEASE_2_3_0-build\src\libhpdfs.a -lcomctl32 -mwindows

.
.
.

obj\Debug\main.o: In function `Z19CUSTOM_RegularTableP13_HPDF_Doc_RecP14_HPDF_Dict_RecffPfiS3_ic':
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:99: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_Rectangle'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:100: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_Stroke'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:102: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_Rectangle'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:103: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_Stroke'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:114: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_MoveTo'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:115: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_LineTo'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:116: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_Stroke'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:125: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_MoveTo'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:126: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_LineTo'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:127: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_Stroke'
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `Z27CUSTOM_RegularTable_AddText20_CUSTOM_TableHandleriiPKhjccP14_HPDF_Dict_Recj':
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:198: undefined reference to `HPDF_Font_GetCapHeight'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:232: undefined reference to `HPDF_Font_MeasureText'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:294: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:300: undefined reference to `HPDF_Font_MeasureText'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:315: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_BeginText'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:316: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_TextRect'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:317: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_EndText'
obj\Debug\main.o: In function `Z13pdf_generatorcPci':
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:347: undefined reference to `HPDF_New'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:353: undefined reference to `HPDF_SetCompressionMode'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:355: undefined reference to `HPDF_GetFont'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:356: undefined reference to `HPDF_GetFont'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:357: undefined reference to `HPDF_GetFont'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:358: undefined reference to `HPDF_GetFont'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:362: undefined reference to `HPDF_LoadPngImageFromFile'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:442: undefined reference to `HPDF_AddPage'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:444: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetSize'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:446: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetLineWidth'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:447: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetLineWidth'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:460: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_DrawImage'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:463: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_BeginText'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:464: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetRGBFill'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:465: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:466: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_TextRect'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:467: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_EndText'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:685: undefined reference to `HPDF_AddPage'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:687: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetSize'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:689: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetLineWidth'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:690: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetLineWidth'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:699: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_DrawImage'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:702: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_BeginText'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:703: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetRGBFill'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:704: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:705: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_TextRect'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:706: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_EndText'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:829: undefined reference to `HPDF_AddPage'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:831: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetSize'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:833: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetLineWidth'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:834: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_SetLineWidth'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:843: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_DrawImage'
C:/Projects/MagicReportsFull/pdf.h:846: undefined reference to `HPDF_Page_BeginText'
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 5 second(s))
50 error(s), 37 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 5 second(s))
```

As you can see, I am using LibHaru library which works flawlesly in guest system. Also i believe problem is not in library itself but in linker.

Project build options -> Linker settings -> Link libraries:

```
libcomdlg32.a
libgdi32.a
libuser32.a
libshlwapi.a
..\..\CustomLibraries\lpng1636-build\libpng16.a
..\..\CustomLibraries\zlib-1.2.11-build\libzlibstatic.a
..\..\CustomLibraries\libharu-RELEASE_2_3_0-build\src\libhpdfs.a
libcomctl32.a
```

I tried to do the same thing in Win7 virtual machine with same results. I am using same files as in guest system. Any ideas what went wrong?

Comment: Have you built `libhpdfs.a` correctly? Is it the only library you should link with, or are there other libraries that you need to link with?

Comment: I've been using that library for several months on guest OS, it require both libpng and zlib listed just before it.

Comment: So you have used the library before in other programs, and haven't had any similar problems with it? Then what makes this project different from some other older project? What settings are different? How does your current build of the library differ from the other builds for the other projects? There must be something you have done differently compared to your other working projects, you just need to find out what.

Comment: Looks like you're building a _debug_ version of your program but linking against a _release_ version of the haru library.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question because i was not sure about linker settings being ok but since nobody said that its wrong i searched  for other problems. So it turns out that i have been using wrong Program Files in Global compiler settings -> Toolchain executables. Also library order was wrong, LibHaru needed to be first and then other dependent libraries. Uninstalled GCC and IDE then installed correct version of GCC + IDE. Now it compiles without problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that reinstalling the compiler might have changed the version of MinGW, and maybe the library isn't compatible between these 2 versions.
I've had similar weird behaviour with MinGW before, and recompiling the dependencies myself with the same compiler fixed the issue (it's a tedious solution though).

- Are the compiler and system exactly the same ? (same architecture, version, etc)
- Check if you havent copied some codeblocks environment specific files from the previous system, maybe codeblocks is trying to compile with options that doesn't apply to your new environment.
- Does the libhpdfs headers have system dependent defines ?
- Did you compile libhpdfs.a yourself ?
- Did you try recompiling it yourself on the virtual machine ?